# How do I write TypeScript can return a type of Map.get() returned value by inference?

Tags: typescript

```
type FuncType<O extends Object> = (option: O) => boolean

export const funcMap: Map<string, Function> = new Map()

const func1: FuncType<Object> = () => true
const func2: FuncType<{prop: number}> = ({ prop }) => prop !== 0
funcMap.set('func1', func1)
funcMap.set('func2', func2)
```

In an other files..

```
const _func2 = funcMap.get('func2')
if (_func2 !== undefined) _func2() // type is Function. I expect that FuncType<{prop: number}>
```

The type of `_func2()` is the Function.
I understand why it is.
How do I write TypeScript can return a type of Map.get() returned value by inference?

Comment: `export const funcMap: Map<string, FuncType<any>> = new Map()` is this sufficient for you?

Comment: no, not sufficient for me.
I want to know what options can be specified for that function.

Comment: There's a way but really tedious. I doubt you would like it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extends the original `Map` interface, overload its `.get()` method to kinda "inject" the type dictionary into it.

```
type FuncType<O extends Object> = (option: O) => boolean

const func1: FuncType<Object> = () => true
const func2: FuncType<{prop: number}> = ({ prop }) => prop !== 0

export const funcMap: MyMap<keyof MyMapStore, Function> = new Map()

funcMap.set('func1', func1)
funcMap.set('func2', func2)

interface MyMapStore {
  func1: typeof func1
  func2: typeof func2
}

interface MyMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  get<P extends keyof MyMapStore>(key: P): MyMapStore[P]
  get(key: K): V
}


// ----- other file ----
import { funcMap } from './somewhere'

const _func1 = funcMap.get('func1')
const _func2 = funcMap.get('func2')
```